# two bundles using the same entities Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony2 under Application A, which i finished and now it was proposed that we will develep Application B which use three tables the Database of Application A , and i was wondering if there is a way to "Share" this Enities between these two Application?
Thank you

Comment: You can use the doctrine commands to generate your entities from your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move those entities to separate Bundle and upload it to private repository.